# Combobox passed as a Control template then as a popup

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a combobox "recent_users" as a control template and then as a poppup. How can I pass the selected value of the popup to the method below?(popup click)

recent_users.SelectedItem.ToString() always returns null.

```
    private void usernameEnter_PreviewMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("testing dropdown");
        ControlTemplate ct = recent_users.Template;
        Popup popup1 = ct.FindName("PART_Popup", recent_users) as Popup;

        if (popup1 != null)
        {
            popup1.Placement = PlacementMode.Top;
        }
        
        recent_users.IsDropDownOpen = true;
        popup1.PreviewMouseUp += new MouseButtonEventHandler((s,e) => popupClick(s,e,recent_users.SelectedItem.ToString()));
    }

    private void popupClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e, String recent)
    {
        usernameEnter.Text = recent;
        Trace.WriteLine("appending norms");
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it because the user has not made any selection in the ComboBox? I have re-written the code slightly

```
private void usernameEnter_PreviewMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    ControlTemplate ct = recent_users.Template;
    Popup popup1 = ct.FindName("PART_Popup", recent_users) as Popup;

    if (popup1 != null)
    {
        popup1.Placement = PlacementMode.Top;
    }

    recent_users.IsDropDownOpen = true;

    // if none selected, set first as selected
    if (recent_users.SelectedIndex < 0 && recent_users.HasItems)
    {
        recent_users.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
    var selectedItem = recent_users.SelectedItem as ComboBoxItem;
    var selectedUser = selectedItem.Content.ToString();

    popup1.PreviewMouseUp += new MouseButtonEventHandler((s, e) => popupClick(s, e, selectedUser));
}
```

But I was wondering adding a handler for PreviewMouseUp event (in the last line) is something that you really want. I would have fetched the selected user in the SelectionChanged of the recent_users rather.